# Why content goes behind appbar android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to get the content below AppBar but it doesn't work. Here is the the code of the layout of my activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".home.HomeActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add_counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/contentFrame"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is the code of the layout of my fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".home.HomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/countersLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/counters_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tryied the solution given in other stackoverflow posts like `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` but it doesn't work. It gives this :

[image]

I have tryied with this `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` and it works but I still would like to understand how to get `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` working.

Comment: Add your main_activity xml code where you are setting navigation drawer menu.

Comment: @Khemraj : OK I have added the code of main_activity.xml

Comment: Wait a bit, i will correct it for you.

Comment: Do you need appBarLayout? I dont see collapsing toolbar in your layout. Or you have added it to hide your toolbar while scrolling list.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your content layout to following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".home.HomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/countersLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/counters_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think this will solve your problem. Because `app:layout_behavior` is not used correctly in your layout. You need to use it on the layout that contains your content which is your `ConstraintLayout` in here, not `LinearLayout`. In addition, It seems that `LinearLayout` in your layout is useless, unless you are going to add something dynamic inside it.

**UPDATE**

OOPS my mistake. I didn't notice that your content is a fragment. Change main layout to following and remove `app:layout_behavior` from your content layout:

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: @Mouss oops sorry, I missed something in your main layout.you need to remove that fragment layout too. updated post.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need AppBarLayout then you can change your MainActivityLayout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add_counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/contentFrame"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```